# How do I make a JAR from a .java file?

Tags: java, jar

I was writing a simple program using a Java application (not application that has projects, but application within a project; *.java*) that has a single frame. Both of the files are *.java* so I can't write a *manifest* needed by the JAR.

The *MyApp.java* starts like a class with package, imports then public class `MyApp` and has a main function, but it's still .java file! I'm writing it in JDeveloper 11g if it helps.

Any ideas how to make a JAR from these files?

Comment: I think this can be accomplish much easier by using packaging tool such as ANT or Maven

Comment: Agree with Chuck. Take a look at ANT. IDEs are great for developing, but you need to understand how things works. java files are compiled via javac to .class files, after this, .class files can be packaged into a jar with the jar command. (Ant has tasks for doing this, even jdeveloper has some wizard for doing this).

Comment: JDeveloper itself should have the capability to create jar files. A quick google search comes up with a howto here: http://tompeez.wordpress.com/2011/06/01/creating-a-jar-file-in-jdeveloper/

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Comment: Go to source dir and run command:-  javac *.java && jar cvf  JarName.jar *.class

Answer (score 137):

Open a command prompt.

Go to the directory where you have your .java files

Create a directory build

Run java compilation from the command line

```
javac -d ./build *.java
```

if there are no errors, in the build directory you should have your class tree

move to the build directory and do a

```
jar cvf YourJar.jar *
```

For adding manifest check jar command line switches

Comment: I've tried compiling from the command line, but I get an error:
Frame1.java:23: package oracle.jdeveloper.layout does not exist

How do I solve that? Sorry for the newbie questions...

Comment: you have to build the classpath referring all the libraries you're referencing in your classes. Check with your jdeveloper installation, there should be some ant build example (build.xml file) and at least a couple of good tutorials on how to use jDeveloper with ANT on Oracle's site.

Comment: @user1303007 take a look here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/adf/part4-098813.html

Comment: I've added an option to my jar command to automatically add the Main-Class to manifest... `jar cfe Main.jar Main *` (I've got confused though, I've had to put the Main-Class name after the output file name.)

Comment: I'd like to point out: `You have to move to build directory`. If you try `jar cvf YourJar.jar ./build/*`, you will have trouble running your jar file later.

Comment: @DarkTrick precisely, similar issues you would get if you forget the -d switch on javac.

Answer (score 43):

Simply with command line:

```
javac MyApp.java
jar -cf myJar.jar MyApp.class
```

Sure IDEs avoid using command line terminal

Comment: The above worked, however I needed to specify the `.class` of myApp. So it was `jar -cf myJar.jar myApp.class`

Comment: Spelling errors here too, and it assumes there is no package statement. Not adequate.

Comment: This worked. Could anyone please decode what's happening here? What's -cf?

Answer (score 21):

Ok this is the solution I would have liked to find, instead here I write it:

First create the directory structure corresponding to the package defined for the .java file, if it is `my.super.application` create the directory `my` and inside it `super` and inside it the .java file `App.java`

then from command line:

```bash
javac -cp /path/to/lib1.jar:/path/to/lib2.jar path/to/my/super/App.java
```

Notice the above will include multiple libraries, if under windows use "," to separate multiple files otherwise under GNU/Linux use ":"
To create a jar file

```bash
jar -cvfe App.jar App my/app/
```

the above will create the application with its corresponding Manifest indicating the App as the main class.

Including the required libraries inside the jar file is not possible using java or jar command line parameters.

You can instead:

1. manually extract libraries to the root folder of the jar file
2. use an IDE such as Netbeans and insert a rule inside post-jar section of `nbproject/build-impl.xml` to extract the libraries inside the jar. See below.

```xml
<target name="-post-jar">
    <!-- Empty placeholder for easier customization. -->
    <!-- You can override this target in the ../build.xml file. -->
    <jar jarfile="${dist.jar}" update="true">
        <zipfileset src="${dist.jar}"                           includes="**/*.class"/>
        <zipfileset src="${file.reference.iText-1.0.8.jar}"     includes="**/*"/>
        <zipfileset src="${file.reference.itextpdf-3.2.1.jar}"  includes="**/*"/>
    </jar>
</target>
```

the `file.reference` names are found inside `project.properties` file after you added the libraries to the Netbeans IDE.

Answer (score 11):

Often you will want to specify a manifest, like so:

```
jar -cvfm myJar.jar myManifest.txt myApp.class
```

Which reads: "create verbose jarFilename manifestFilename", followed by the files you want to include. Verbose means print messages about what it's doing.

Note that the name of the manifest file you supply can be anything, as `jar` will automatically rename it and put it into the right directory within the jar file.

Answer (score 6):

This can be done without terminal, directly from IDE. Netbeans, for example.

1. Create a separate project with packages (Create Project - Java - Java Class Library).
2. Put your .java classes there.
3. Build this project.
4. Go to your project folder and find build and dist folders there.
5. Find .jar file in your dist folder.
6. Get your other project and add this .jar file to project libraries.
7. You can now reference classes from this library and its methods directly from code, if import is automatically done for you.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another fancy way of doing this:

```
$ ls | grep .java | xargs -I {} javac {} ; jar -cf myJar.jar *.class
```

Which will grab all the .java files ( `ls | grep .java` ) from your current directory and compile them into .class (`xargs -I {} javac {}`) and then create the jar file from the previously compiled classes (`jar -cf myJar.jar *.class`).

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps the most beginner-friendly way to compile a JAR from your Java code is to use an IDE (integrated development environment; essentially just user-friendly software for development) like Netbeans or Eclipse.

- Install and set-up an IDE. [Here is the latest version of Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/).
- Create a project in your IDE and put your Java files inside of the project folder.
- Select the project in the IDE and export the project as a JAR. Double check that the appropriate java files are selected when exporting.

You can always do this all very easily with the command line. Make sure that you are in the same directory as the files targeted before executing a command such as this:

```
javac YourApp.java
jar -cf YourJar.jar YourApp.class
```

...changing "YourApp" and "YourJar" to the proper names of your files, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

If you have one simple main class(let's say Count.class), and want a jar with a MANIFEST file that points to this class as the entry point, you can do this:

```
jar cfe app.jar Count Count.class
```

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

Comment: How to include a `.jar` file (library) inside the new jar?