# SUMO SRTM osmosis plugin

Tags: java, openstreetmap, osmosis

I have been trying to run the SRTM-osmosis plugin (https://github.com/locked-fg/osmosis-srtm-plugin) for quite some time now. In the wiki, it is mentioned that you should move the compiled jar to the directory (/~.openstreetmaps/osmosis/plugins). I can't find the .jar file and don't know to generate it as mentioned in the wiki ?
Anyone faced a similar problem with the SRTM plugin ?!

Comment: Try creating the .jar file from the java file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9941296/how-do-i-make-a-jar-from-a-java   `javac myfile.java`
`jar -cf myJar.jar myfile`

Answer (score 0):

The documentation was updated (https://github.com/locked-fg/osmosis-srtm-plugin). Just copied the .jar file to (~/.openstreetmaps/osmosis/plugins) and used the command: osmosis --read-xml map.osm --write-srtm tagName=ele  --write-xml map_with_srtm.osm