# Android Studio 2.0 using external projects with jar and source files

Tags: java, android, linux, git, android-studio

i've been searching all the web for a definitive solution for this simple problem of adding an external directory with .java files and .jar libraries to my Android Studio project.

Here's what I want to do:

Create a default project in Android Studio, and import from git the library I will work on, which is a bunch of .java files and a .jar (jsoup). These java files need this jsoup. The java files are not for Android, just simple java files.

I need it to be from github because I'm working on this lib and I need AndroidStudio to automatically update it to its newest version.

This is how I compile my project:

```
javac -cp ".:jsoup-1.8.3.jar" Main.java Class1.java Class2.java;
```

Then I run:

```
java -cp ".:jsoup-1.8.3.jar" Main
```

Well, I already loaded this library from github using Android Studio, so now I have:

```
Project/app/src/main/java/com.myname.myapp

Project/MyLibraryFromGithub
```

Of course I seen answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16639227) and I followed everything, but there are some problems. For example, it kept searching for a AndroidManifest.xml file which I don't know how to write because it's a simple java project, not a Android Project. Also, I think this answer is outdated, and won't work properly in AndroidStudio 2.0.

I've read some tutorials on Gradle but it won't say anything about external folders and so. Also, when I make it happen, how do I import my library? For example, in

```
Project/app/src/main/java/com.myname.myapp/Main.java
```

How do I import the library? `import myLibrary`? Or I just need to create new objects with the classe's names? Like `Class1 myObject = new...`?

This is so congusing! I whish I could compile everything by hand, Gradle is hiding too much from me and I can't find a good tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

To add an external jar to your project you should do the following steps:

1. Select `File >> New >> New Module`.
2. Select `Import JAR/AAR Package`.
3. Give the file name in the `File` name text box and click on `Finish`.
4. Select `File >> Project Structure`.
5. Select `app` under the `modules` section on the left hand side.
6. Choose `Dependencies` tab at the top.
7. Click on the `+` on the right hand side.
8. Select `Module Dependency`
9. Select the `JAR` file that you have just imported.
10. Close both the open windows by clicking `OK`

Comment: but it's not only jar, it's a lot of source files too!!

Comment: I would say that you compile all the dependent files into a single jar and then proceed. See this stack Overflow answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9941296/how-do-i-make-a-jar-from-a-java

Comment: but I wanted to use gradle because its purpose is to build everything with one click :c

Comment: :) You may use gradle. But I am a beginner and this is the approach that I have found to be very easy and error free. All the best :)

Comment: By the way.. All the above step are one time. There is no need of doing it again and again with every compilation. So I also dont see the point is using Gradle :\

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

1. Place X.jar into the libs folder
2. Right click on X.jar and 'Add as Library'
3. (In build.gradle) Place this in dependencies: `compile files('libs/X.jar')`

Comment: but it's not only jar, it's a lot of source files too!!