# running java program in IntelliJ terminal

Tags: intellij-15

Below is a screenshot of IntelliJ on my computer with a terminal up.

[image]

I thought I should be able to just type `java random_uniform`in the terminal to run the program but it complains withe the error message shown in the screenshot.

I have looked at similar questions to mine but still wasn't able to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The terminal in IntelliJ is just your shell (if you're on unix) and cmd.exe-like command prompt (if you're on Windows). There's no magic.

So to run program in terminal you need to compile it as usually and run binary.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9941296/how-do-i-make-a-jar-from-a-java) is an answer about how to compile Java program