# How to make a runnable .jar file in java with cmd or powershell our own?

Tags: java, machine-learning

I tried many times by making a manifest file with notepad by seeing YouTube videos but it can't be worked

Comment: Could you show us your effort?

Answer (score 0):

this is quite simple:
open cmd and `cd` into your directory.
then `javac YourProg.java` where MyApp.java is your code.
then `jar -cf YourJar.jar YourProg.class` where YourJar.jar is the new file and YourProg.class is your class.
then you shold have your .jar file in the current cmd directory
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9941385/14154066 - similar answer
[how-do-i-make-a-jar-from-a-java-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9941296/how-do-i-make-a-jar-from-a-java-file) - similar question

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a standalone runnable jar file, you can use

`jar -cvf your_prefer_filename.jar -e your_full_main_class_file -C directory_contains_all_classes/ .`

it will generate a jar file called `your_prefer_filename.jar` and then you can run with

`jar -jar your_prefer_filename.jar`