# Import custom classes in java

Tags: java

I have a `Main` java class which has the `main()` method. In this method I want to use another class of that I wrote `Person`. Both classes are under the same package so I understand I don't need to import the `Person` class and I can use it right away.

Should I compile the `Person` class first and then the `Main` or not?

I tried to compile just the `main` and I got error:

> cannot find symbol Person

Comment: If you use an IDE, such as IntelliJ or Eclipse, you never have to worry about issues like this.

Comment: check this, it's about making a Jar containing many .class file, but should point you to the right direction also with compilation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9941296/how-do-i-make-a-jar-from-a-java-file/9941411#9941411

Answer (score 2):

> My question is should I compile the Person class first and then the
> Main or not.

You could, but there is no need to do that given the simple requirements you describe.  The 2 could be compiled together if you like.  You do not necessarily need to compile Person first.